# Value from appsettings.json in model .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

In my model class, I am trying to read a value from appsettings.json and set CDN url of the images, according to the environment (development, production). It is a .net core app.

**Model**

```
public class Person
{
   public int Id  { get; set; }

   public int ProfileImageUrl => $"{Configuration["CdnUrl"]}/profiles/{Id}.jpg"
}
```

**Index.cshtml (Razor Page)**

```
@page
@model IndexModel

<img src="@Model.ProfileImageUrl " />
```

**Index.cshtml.cs**

```
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    Person = await _context.Person.FirstAsync();
}
```

**App settings**

```
appsettings.Development.json
{
   "CdnUrl": "/images"
}

appsettings.Production.json
{
   "CdnUrl": "https://images.domain.com"
}
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the configuration source? For instance, are you using the built-in ASP.NET Core configuration services?

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET Core MVC application?

Comment: It is .net core. It is stated in the title and in the tags. It added to the comment aswell

Comment: See [How to inject dependencies into models in asp.net core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39276939/how-to-inject-dependencies-into-models-in-asp-net-core)

Comment: .NET Core has several application models, one of which is the MVC application model. Is what you're building an MVC application?

Comment: @MarkG this solution is really complicated for something that should be simple, like it used to be in asp.net

Comment: @ShaunLuttin It is a razor page

Comment: Given that it's a razor page application, is the Person class a simple class or is it a `PageModel`?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin Person is a simple model

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple way to do that . Since you've configured the **CdnUrl** in your **appsettings.json** file , let's create a **TagHelper** with an **IConfiguration** property injected , so that we can calculate the final URL at runtime:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("cdn-img")]
public class CdnImgTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration{ get; set; } 
    public CdnImgTagHelper(IConfiguration configuration) {
        this.Configuration = configuration;
    }
    public string Src { get; set; }
    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.TagName = "img";

        var CdnUrlBase = Configuration["CdnUrl"];
        // make sure CndUrlBase endwith "/"
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(CdnUrlBase)) { CdnUrlBase ="/"; }
        if (!CdnUrlBase.EndsWith("/")) { CdnUrlBase = CdnUrlBase + "/"; }

        // make sure src don't start with "/"
        if (Src.StartsWith("/")) { Src= Src.Substring(0, Src.Length - 1); }

        output.Attributes.SetAttribute("src", CdnUrlBase + Src);
    }
}
```

after importing the **CdnImgTagHelper** into your **_ViewsImports** file , we can use it like this :

```
<cdn-img src="mfcpv.png"></cdn-img>
```

Since I've configured my **appsettings.json** with a

```
"CdnUrl": "https://i.stack.imgur.com"
```

the generated img looks like  :

[image: cdn tag helper demo]